# Why not showing all post by default in my jquery filter

Tags: php, filters, ajax, jquery, wp-reset-postdata

Hello Expert Developer,
Can you please take a look on it, What i did messed up?

```
function mysite_filter_function(){

//groups checkboxes
if( $groups = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' ) ) ) :
$groups_terms = array();

foreach( $groups as $group ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['group_' . $group->term_id ] ) && $_POST['group_' . $group->term_id] == 'on' )
         $groups_terms[] = $group->slug;
}
endif;



$tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

if ( ! empty( $groups_terms ) ) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $groups_terms,
    );
}



$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_type' => 'course',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        // echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
        // get_template_part( 'customcourse');
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">
                <div class="course_post_card">
                    <div class="course_title">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course_footer">
                        <div class="course_footer_location">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <span><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'skips_size', TRUE);?></span> </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="course_footer_date">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'skips_width', TRUE);?></span> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>


        <?php

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'No posts found';
endif;

die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'mysite_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'mysite_filter_function');
```

and this is my course page

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Courses Pages
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/

get_header();
//Add AJAX path to use in load-posts.js
$getPath = array('ajaxURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));

 ?>
    
<body <?php body_class( 'site-content' ); ?>>

    <div class="container" style="padding: 80px 0px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
                    <?php
                    if( $groups = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' ) ) ) :
                      echo '<ul class="groups-list">';
                        echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='all' id='all'> All</label>";

                      foreach( $groups as $group ) :
                         echo '<input type="checkbox" class="" id="group_' . $group->term_id . '" name="group_' . $group->term_id . '" /><label for="group_' . $group->term_id . '">' . $group->name . '</label>';
                       endforeach;
                       echo '</ul>';
                     endif;
                   ?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row all-post">
                <!-- All the post -->
            </div>

            

            <!-- Load More Button -->
            <div class="col-md-12 align-self-center text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="loadMore">Load More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
<script>

$('#filter').change(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type:filter.attr('method'),
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            //filter.find('button').text('Processing...');
        },
        success:function(data){
            //filter.find('button').text('Filter');
            $('.all-post').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please elaborate on your problem. No one can tell you what you messed up if you don't explain what you're trying to do and what's not working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, Actually I try to achive by default show all post, when the course page load show all post and when user check the cat then show only specific post based on cat id. I believe you understand sir sorry for my bad english.

Comment: can anyone help me about it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

@HappyArif You just kept a line in your code that needs to be changed if there is a Category selected.

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'post_type' => 'course',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
);
```

This have `'posts_per_page' => -1` which needs to be changed to `'posts_per_page' => 9, 'paged' => $paged` to make the categorized ajax call as Paged query.

```
if ( ! empty( $groups_terms ) ) {
$paged = 2; //This needs to be the Paged Request Number.
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'post_type' => 'course',
  'posts_per_page' => 9,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query'      => $tax_query
);
}
else
{
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'post_type' => 'course',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
}
```

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: I've editted my code, check this one and let me know. @HappyArif

Comment: Sorry I again try but not working, what i need, I need when cate4gory unchecked should be show all the post, and when category checked then show only selected category post

Comment: Try running your code only with limited results first and remove posts_per_page => -1 and add posts_per_page => 9 
Is it returning 9 posts rather than all first ??

Comment: when i used 9 i get same  like previous, but its not visible when website load

Comment: I want when website load and show all post, untill user check the category show all post